apk installed app is not visible in other users except admin user after upgrade to android14
I usually install several apks necessary for my work, they are internally released so not available over googleplay.
We have several users on the device, so multiple users can use their own profile.
However, after recent updates, these apps disappear from other user accounts. And It seems no way to install them.
More annoying, one app is still visible in the other user accounts however it cannot be opened. It flashes then exits.
Can anyone share some experience how to fix this problem, or maybe in android14, the apk installed app cannot be used in other users by design? If this is the truth we might consider to go back to more expensive iOS device.

Please read the tags before posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].
